# Order a list of zipfiles, by date modified, then unzip them in that order

Tags: zip, xargs, exec

I have a list of zip files, that must be extracted by date modified, they contain updated images and the strange way the local mls provides them means that newer zip files container newer versions of those images.

How I can run a command to list the files, then unzip them in that order, oldest to newest?

I can output the list correctly in `ls`, but cannot get it to work.

```
ls -tr photo20* | -exec unzip -o {} -d /home/tar/public_html/images/listing_photos/idx/ \;
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
for f (./*.zip(Om)) unzip $f
```

Where the `Om` glob qualifier is to reverse order by modification time (newest last).

With `bash` and GNU `ls`:

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C
  eval "files=($(ls -drt --quoting-style=shell-always ./*.zip))"
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    unzip "$file"
  done
)
```

Or with `bash` 4.4+ and GNU `find` and GNU `sort` and recent version of GNU `cut`:

```
readarray -td '' files < <(
  LC_ALL=C find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.zip' ! -name '.*' \
    -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
    sort -zn |
    cut -zf2-)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  unzip "$file"
done
```

If you can guarantee the file names won't contain newline characters, with GNU `xargs`, you can do:

```
ls -rtd ./*.zip | xargs -rd '\n' -n1 unzip
```

If you can guarantee that the file names won't contain whitespace, single quote, double quote, backslash characters or sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters, and that there's at least one non-hidden zip file, with any `xargs` implementation, you could do:

```
ls -rtd ./*.zip | xargs -n1 unzip
```

Answer (score -1):

Try (untested):

```
for i in $(ls -rt *.zip)
do
   unzip ${i}
done
```